# How to make pressing a selected tab bar item reload my view

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a view contained in a tabbarcontroller.  When a user clicks on one of the items I load data into that view.   However, if they click that item again I want to reload the view again.

So far I am running the didSelectViewController method in my tabbarcontroller and from there I  popToRootViewControllerAnimated.   However it appears that popToRootViewControllerAnimated doesn't execute the viewdidload, viewwillload, or viewwillappear methods, so I am stuck as to how to reload...

Answer (score 0):

While it may not be UI friendly to refresh an already selected tabbar item (user already selected that item and it shows it as selected. They would then expect to pull down to refresh), have you tried adding `[viewController.view setNeedsDisplay];` in your `didSelectViewController`?